# Custom contextmenu won't work in Firefox on Mac

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this custom contextmenu. It works perfect in every browser, except Firefox on Mac computers.

I have created it, so when the user right-click, the original menu will be hidden, after then, the custom menu, will be removed, if it already is shown *(so only one menu will be shown at the time)*. And then finally, the menu will be created.

I also add another function, so that the menu also will be removed, if the user clicks anywhere else at the page.

As I said: This is only a problem in Firefox on Mac.

**Here's my code:**

```
var contextmenu = $('<div class="contextmenu">'
                    + '<span class="row">First Row</span>'
                    + '<span class="row">Second Row</span>'
                    + '<span class="row">Third Row</span>'
                    + '<span class="row about">Fourth Row</span>'
                    +'</div>');

// Show Contentmenu if user right-click anywhere
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.contextmenu').remove();
    contextmenu.appendTo("body").css({
        top: event.pageY,
        left: event.pageX
    });
});

// Hide Contentmenu if user click anywhere
$(document).click(function() {
    $('.contextmenu').remove();
});
```

I've also tried to use
`$(document).bind("contextmenu", function() {...});` instead of `$(document).click(function() {...});` but no difference here.

I really don't understand why this won't work in Firefox on Macs, when it works fine in Firefox on Windows and all the other browsers.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nNN2b/)

Comment: It works for me in Firefox.

Comment: It seems that, it is Firefox on Mac, where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to hope that your Firefox issue on Mac is the same Firefox issue that I'm getting using Firefox on Linux.

This piece of code:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    $('.contextmenu').remove();
});
```

is actually hiding the contextmenu just after it appears, all in the same click. My contextmenus in Ubuntu appear on right click *onmousedown* instead of onclick like those on Windows, so the custom contextmenu is being created and then it is immediately being hidden once the mouse button is released and moved slightly.

Modifying it so that the contextmenu is instead hidden onmousedown fixes the issue for me on Firefox:

```
$(document).mousedown(function() {
    $('.contextmenu').remove();
});
```

Hopefully that also fixes the issue for Firefox on Mac.

Comment: It works better now. But I have another question. Now I can't click on any rows at the menu, without the menu to disappear. So how to I avoid the menu from disappearing, if the click happens inside the contextmenu it self?

Comment: Fixed it by adding `if( !$(evt.target).is('.contextmenu, .row') ) {
        $('.contextmenu').remove();
    }` inside the function. Thank you very much! :D

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me :

```
$(document).on("mousedown", function(event){
                    if (!$(event.target).closest(".context-menu").length)
                        cmenu.hide();
                });
```